# How to display related items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display related experiences below the local experiences. I tried to do it using `@experiences= Experience.excludes(house.experiences)` but didnt work out. Can I get any suggestion how to do that.

```
<h3>Local experiences</h3>

<section class="list-box">
  <% @house.experiences.each do |experience| %>

  <p>
    <%= experience.name %>
    <% if logged_in? && current_user.role == "customer" %>
    <%= link_to "Make Enquiry", new_message_path(receiver_id: experience.supplier.user) %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Make Enquiry", new_customer_path %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</section>

<h3>Related experiences</h3>

<section class="list-box">
  <% @experiences.each do |experience| %>

  <p>
    <%= experience.name %>
    <% if logged_in? && current_user.role == "customer" %>
    <%= link_to "Make Enquiry", new_message_path(receiver_id: experience.supplier.user) %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Make Enquiry", new_customer_path %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

Comment: What is *excludes*? And what you mean by *didnt work out*?

Comment: _but didnt work out_ what is the error ?

Comment: excludes is just reverse of Include method is rails and Its seems like you want excludes each house experiences ryt?  I want to know how house and experiences are related In DB (has_many or has_one)?

Comment: @VKatz Is there a method called `excludes` There is [*exclude?*](https://apidock.com/rails/String/exclude%3F)

Comment: house has_many :experiences @VKatz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method called `excludes` in the rails model. There is only `exclude?`, which is a instance method of class `String`. Refer [here](https://apidock.com/rails/String/exclude%3F).

For your issue, maybe something like below would work given that `house_id` is the foreign_key in your experience table.

```
@experiences = Experience.where.not(house_id: house.experiences)
```

You may refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) for more `not` conditions.